# Determine the probability of an outcome more than 100 from the mean

Tags: statistics

We are to use T-Shev to place a bound on this probability. A random variable $Y$ has mean $144$ and standard deviation $60$.

What I have:

$1/k^2 \ge P(Y-\mu) \ge \sigma k$

$1/k^2 \ge P(Y-144\ge100)$

$1/k^2 \ge P(Y-144 \ge 60(100/60))$

My last line is $0.36 \ge P(Y\ge144\ge100)$, which is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \Pr(Y > 144 + 100 \text{ or } Y < 144-100) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr \left( \frac{Y-144}{60} > \frac{100}{60} \text{ or } \frac{Y-144}{60} < \frac{-100}{60} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr \left(\left| \frac{Y-144}{60} \right| > \frac{100}{60} \right) \le \left( \frac{60}{100} \right)^2 = 0.36.
\end{align}